# How to vectorize this operation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Say I have two lists (always the same length):

```
l0 = [0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0] 
l1 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8]
```

I have the following rules for intersections and unions I need to apply when comparing these lists element-wise:

```
# union and intersect
uni = [0]*len(l0)
intersec = [0]*len(l0)
for i in range(len(l0)):
    if l0[i] == l1[i]:
        uni[i] = l0[i]
        intersec[i] = l0[i]
    else:
        intersec[i] = 0  
        if l0[i] == 0:
            uni[i] = l1[i]
        elif l1[i] == 0:
            uni[i] = l0[i]
        else:
            uni[i] = [l0[i], l1[i]]
```

Thus, the desired output is:

```
uni: [0, [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8] 
intersec: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0]
```

While this works, I need to do this with several hundred very large lists (each, with thousands of elements), so I am looking for a way to vectorize this. I tried using `np.where` and various masking strategies, but that went nowhere fast. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

*** EDIT ***

Regarding

```
uni: [0, [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8]
```

versus

```
uni: [0, [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, [0, 8]]
```

I'm still fighting the 8 versus [0, 8] in my mind. The lists are derived from BIO tags in system annotations (see [IOB labeling of text chunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging))), where each list element is a character index in a document and the vakue is an assigned enumerated label. 0 represents a label representing no annotation (i.e., used for determining negatives in a confusion matrix); while non zero elements represent assigned enumerated labels for that character. Since I am ignoring true negatives, I think I can say 8 is equivalent to [0, 8]. As to whether this simplifies things, I am not yet sure.

*** EDIT 2 ***

I'm using `[0, 8]` to keep things simple and to keep the definitions of `intersection` and `union` consistent with set theory.

Comment: Vectorizing intersection is straightforward.. `np.where(a0==l1,a0,0)` where `a0 = np.array(l0)`. Vectorizing your `uni` will be tough because the output is not a valid `numpy` array. It _could be_, but its `dtype` would be `object`, nullifying most vectorization gains from the library

Comment: The mix of lists and scalars in `uni` is a good indication that a fully 'vectorized' solution is not possible.  Same is true if the solution has lists (or arrays) of differing lengths.

Comment: Can you define _nowhere fast_? How fast is your solution now with several hundred large lists?

Comment: Er, nowhere fast meaning: I had no solution! Nothing meant in terms of speed. I had the intersection, but the union was the sticking point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stay away from calling them 'intersection' and 'union', since those operations have well-defined meanings on sets and the operation you're looking to perform is neither of them.

However, to do what you want:

```
l0 = [0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0]
l1 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8]

values = [
    (x
     if x == y else 0,
     0
     if x == y == 0
     else x if y == 0
     else y if x == 0
     else [x, y]) 
    for x, y in zip(l0, l1)
]

result_a, result_b = map(list, zip(*values))

print(result_a)
print(result_b)
```

This is more than enough for thousands, or even millions of elements since the operation is so basic. Of course, if we're talking billions, you may want to look at numpy anyway.

Comment: Not that the solution is a bit simpler still for tuples instead of lists, but the example asked for lists.

Comment: I accepted your answer, because it indeed is simple and is generalizing to my requirements quite nicely. I have yet to do any speed tests.

Comment: Not bad! For the modification to do my "union" and "intersection" compared to my previous code chunk, I get:                            
`old union: 10.6 µs ± 44.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`. 
`old intersection:10.9 µs ± 82 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`. 
`new union: 656 ns ± 9.45 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`. 
`new intersection: 653 ns ± 11.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

Comment: @horcle_buzz clearly you are not unpacking the final `map` object

Comment: How is this (running on lists with many more elements):

`17.1 ns ± 0.276 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)`
`20.5 ns ± 0.456 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each) `

Answer (score 0):

Semi vectorized solution for union and full for intersection:

```
import numpy as np

l0 = np.array(l0)
l1 = np.array(l1)
intersec = np.zeros(l0.shape[0])
intersec_idx = np.where(l0==l1)
intersec[intersec_idx] = l0[intersec_idx]
intersec = intersec.astype(int).tolist()
```

---

```
union = np.zeros(l0.shape[0])
union_idx = np.where(l0==l1)
union[union_idx] = l0[union_idx]
no_union_idx = np.where(l0!=l1)
union = union.astype(int).tolist()
for idx in no_union_idx[0]:
    union[idx] = [l0[idx], l1[idx]]
```

and the output:

```
>>> intersection
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0]
>>> union  
[0, [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, [0, 8]]
```

NB: I think your original union solution is incorrect. See the last output 8 vs [0,8]

Comment: No harm in including the OP's code, especially if you are correcting the result, or doing timings.  If the OP provides a good [mcve] I often copy the code and data to my own session, and then develop my own solution.  That allows me to compare results and timings.

Comment: I'm still fighting the `8` versus `[0, 8]` in my mind. The lists are derived from BIO tags in system annotations, where each list element is a character index in a document. `0` represents a label representing no annotation (i.e., used for determining negatives in a confusion matrix); while non zero elements represent assigned enumerated labels for that character. Since I am ignoring true negatives, I think I can say `8` is equivalent to `[0, 8]`. As to whether this simplifies things, I am not yet sure.

Comment: I like this answer, but I need to do some benchmark tests on real data before I decide which to accept. CPU time seems to be the big bottleneck.

Comment: The only thing that makes me nervous, is the use of the name `union` for the array, especially, since there is a method of the same name. That's why I chose `uni`.